# Access Location Service directly From the App in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dictionary, dart, location

I want to add a feature, in which users can turn their location on or off directly from the app without opening the setting, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out following package: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

That should open a dialog, requesting the location permission